# Read specific value of an object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using an api that return this object:

```
   { 
        "0155894402285712": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "A0242", "name": "Codice+tessera" }, 
        "0155894402283800": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "LZZMRN55L53C003Z", "name": "Codice+Fiscale" } 
    }
```

I need to extract the value A0242 and LZZMRN55L53C003Z but the only things that I know are the name "Codice+tessera" and "Codice+fiscale". How can I read these values? Maybe my question is stupid but really I'm losing my brain today...

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear. Do you want to get `value` based on `name`?

Comment: Yes adiga, sorry if it's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const data = {
  "0155894402285712": {
    "type": "GBUserFieldText",
    "value": "A0242",
    "name": "Codice+tessera"
  },
  "0155894402283800": {
    "type": "GBUserFieldText",
    "value": "LZZMRN55L53C003Z",
    "name": "Codice+Fiscale"
  }
};

// get an array of all the values of this data.
const arrayOfValues = Object.values(data);
// filter this array in order to find the one which the name you want
const selectedObj = arrayOfValues.find(obj => obj.name === 'Codice+tessera');
// get the value of this object.
const selectedValue = selectedObj.value;
console.log(selectedValue);
```

```
// You can also make a function findValueOf(name):
const findValueOf = name =>
    arrayOfValues.find(obj => obj.name === name) &&
    arrayOfValues.find(obj => obj.name === name).value;

// and use it for example:
console.log(findValueOf('Codice+tessera')); // "A0242"
console.log(findValueOf('Codice+Fiscale')); // "LZZMRN55L53C003Z"
```

Comment: using find twice is not a good practice you can better store result is some variable and then access `value` property or you can use default value `( arrayOfValues.find(obj => obj.name === name) || {} ).value`

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then access `value` key's value

```js
let obj =  { 
        "0155894402285712": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "A0242", "name": "Codice+tessera" }, 
        "0155894402283800": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "LZZMRN55L53C003Z", "name": "Codice+Fiscale" } 
}
    
Object.values(obj).forEach(({value})=>{
  console.log(value)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` to loop and get the `value`

```js
var obj = {"0155894402285712":{"type":"GBUserFieldText","value":"A0242","name":"Codice+tessera"},"0155894402283800":{"type":"GBUserFieldText","value":"LZZMRN55L53C003Z","name":"Codice+Fiscale"}}

var resut = Object.values(obj).map(o => o.value);
console.log(resut);
```

If you want to match the name and value, you can use `reduce`

```js
var obj = {"0155894402285712":{"type":"GBUserFieldText","value":"A0242","name":"Codice+tessera"},"0155894402283800":{"type":"GBUserFieldText","value":"LZZMRN55L53C003Z","name":"Codice+Fiscale"}}

var resut = Object.values(obj).reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.name]: v.value}), {});
console.log(resut);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find `A0242` from the value "Codice+tessera" that you have, you need something different than the other answers:

```js
var data = { 
        "0155894402285712": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "A0242", "name": "Codice+tessera" }, 
        "0155894402283800": { "type": "GBUserFieldText", "value": "LZZMRN55L53C003Z", "name": "Codice+Fiscale" } 
    }

const values = ["Codice+tessera", "Codice+fiscale"]
const results = values.map(v => Object.values(data).find(datum => datum.name === v)).map(v => v.value)
console.log(results) // [ "A0242", "LZZMRN55L53C003Z" ]
```